# Override Publish within UIRef in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an UI library with this code:

```
<Fragment>
  <UI Id="My_UI">
    <Dialog Id="Dialog_A">
      <Control Id="Button_Next" Type="PushButton" Text="Next">
        <Publish ... />
      </Control>
    </Dialog>
  </UI>
</Fragment>
```

And then I have my main project with a reference to this library.

```
<Product>
  <UIRef Id="My_UI" />
</Product>
```

The problem is that I cannot add a new `Publish` event. I tried to do this, but then it doesn't work at all.

```
<Product>
  <UI Id="My_UI">
<DialogRef Id="Dialog_A" />
      <Publish Dialog="Dialog_A" Control="Button_Next"
               Event="DoAction" Value="GenInstallReview">1</Publish>
  </UI>
</Product>
```

How can I extend the dialog with a new `Publish` in the main application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add control events but you cannot override existing ones. Open your .msi with Orca and inspect the `ControlEvent` table rows for `Dialog_A`. When you have multiple rows for the same dialog/button combination, you have to follow [the rules specified here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).